# Create an account by calling REST APIs

Tags: rest

I logged on to a website and it asked me this "Call our APIs and we'll call you back". The structure is "/users/:id/apply". I wonder how can I enter this type of site which may require me to check basic auth with my token as password.

Comment: I think will be better if you provide more information about the web service, and the web if its not private

Comment: @user1852777: I think there's a competition on that website, to find the relevant username/password?

Answer (score 0):

If the structure is "/users/:id/apply" you can call with your id :

For example : your user is Alladin and your password "open sesame"

use : /users/Aladdin/apply

and for basic authentication add this in your header:

Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
Base64("Aladdin:open sesame") = "QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ=="

Comment: sorry but how can I find the website's header to add the basic authen?

Comment: You should add the basic auth in the request header you can use a google chrome extension to make REST requests if you want see "Advanced REST client" for Google Chrome

Comment: Thank you very much. I did it. Many thks to you.

Comment: I think Base64("Aladdin:open sesame") is a method execution. @user1852777 Are you sure it work?

Comment: @Corinnekm: Your anwswer doen't work :) I has completed competition on that website. It's a interesting test :)